# Batch File to rename filenames from multiple directories

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple *.jpg files located in folders within a main root folder. I'm after a simple batch file that will rename all the files to it's foldername. For  example:

```
Orphan
---Gambia
------GAM001
---------G123.jpg
---------G456.jpg
---------GX12.jpg
------GAM002
---------G789.jpg
---------G012.jpg
---------G112.jpg
```

And i would like it to look like this:

```
Orphan
---Gambia
------GAM001
---------GAM001.jpg
---------GAM001 (1).jpg
---------GAM001 (2).jpg
------GAM002
---------GAM002.jpg
---------GAM002 (1).jpg
---------GAM002 (2).jpg
```

So i'm after a batch file that I can run from the Main Root folder.

Sorry in advance as I am new to all of this and I thought I would give it a go into something that I am finding very interesting!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want us to write your code for you?? or you already have code to show us, and you have problems you want to ask questions about?

Comment: ***Show your code.***

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\orphan"
FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*) DO (
 PUSHD "%%a"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-n "%%~nxa*.jpg" 2^>nul'
 ) DO REN "%%f" "%%f.jpg"
 SET /a count=0
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "*.jpg"  2^>nul'
 ) DO ECHO REN "%%f" "%%~nxa (!count!).jpg"&SET /a count +=1
 IF EXIST "%%~nxa (0).jpg" ECHO REN "%%~nxa (0).jpg" "%%~nxa.jpg"
 POPD 
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

First step is to process the names of the directories, recursively into `%%a`. These are then `push`ed (which switches to the nominated directory, `%%`) and the main process executed before executing a `pop` to restore the original directory.

The main process first reads the directory for (*dirnameanything*.jpg) and sorts in reverse-name order to ensure the longest name is first. Then any names found are renamed with an extra ".jpg" This means that if the directory has already been processed, (eg) GAM002.jpg may exist, so it is renamed `gam002.jpg.jpg` and hence `gam002.jpg` will not exist after this first rename - and the same goes for `gam002 (1)` - it is now `gam002 (1).jpg.jpg`. Even if `gam002.jpg.jpg` already existed, this method is safe because the renaming is performed in reverse-name order, so `gam002.jpg.jpg` would have been renamed `gam002.jpg.jpg.jpg` before an attempt is made to rename `gam002.jpg` to `gam002.jpg.jpg`

Next step is the real rename sequence. Each `.jpg` is listed and *then* processed, so the original list of files is renamed, avoiding the problem with encountering an already-renamed file. Each one is simply renamed with an increasing `count` in parentheses after the name of the parent directory.

Finally, "*parentdirectoryname* (0).jpg" is renamed to "*parentdirectoryname*.jpg" and all is complete.